# Use ANT to create EAR for IBM WAS server without RAD or RBU

Tags: ant, ibm-rad

Is it possible to create and use IBM Ant tasks without installing RAD (Ratinal Application Developer) or RBU (Rational Build Utility).  I would like to instead just use ANT and copy any jars necessary for the tasks to run.  I have tried this but get exceptions where more classes are necessary.  We normally run the builds in a headless ant build but it is becoming increasing costly to keep this up since the different build servers require a license for the RAD or RBU install.  Any thoughts on this?

I have done this so far:

```
<path id="was_classpath">
    <fileset dir="c:\rad_extension\lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>


<taskdef name="earExport" classname="com.ibm.etools.j2ee.ant.EARExport"
       classpathref="was_classpath" />
<taskdef name="projectBuild" classname="com.ibm.etools.ant.extras.ProjectBuild"
       classpathref="was_classpath" />
<taskdef name="projectGetErrors" classname="com.ibm.etools.ant.extras.ProjectGetErrors"
       classpathref="was_classpath" />

<projectBuild ProjectName="MyProject"
       failonerror="false" DebugCompilation="true" BuildType="full" />
```

I have created the folder "C:\rad_extension\lib" with the jars:

```
antextras.jar
antj2ee.jar
antserver.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_.jar
org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.nl1_1.1.200.v200809240100.jar
org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.nl2_1.1.200.v200809240100.jar
org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks_1.1.201.v200811060900.jar
resources-ant.jar
```

But I am still getting the following error:

taskdef A class needed by class com.ibm.etools.j2ee.ant.EARExport cannot be found: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException using the classloader

Answer (score 0):

You are still going to need the ANT runtime jars.  In my case RAD 8.0.4 there are in:
{install-dir}\SDPShared\plugins\og.apache.ant_1.7.1.v.20100518\lib*

Depending on what tasks your build uses, you may need a few other jars.  You can figure out which ones by looking at the Ant->Runtime->Tasks tab in Windows->Preferences.